# When is it acceptable to pronounce acronyms for EVs

Tags: acronyms, language-change

As a place of innovation electric vehicles having a growing number of acronyms with increasing length.  It is common to call electric vehicles EVs in writing and in speech.

My question is about longer acronyms for subclasses of EVs: when can the written form of plug-in hybrid electric vehicle “PHEV” be pronounced as /fɛv/ instead of P.H.E.V?  Can we expect this to become more common in time?

Same goes for battery electric vehicles as /bɛv/, hybrid electric vehicle as /hɛv/, and extended range electric vehicle as something like /i.ɹɛv/ depending on dialect.

Comment: Do you pronounce EV on its own as /ɛv/?

Comment: Where's this innovation place you reference?

Comment: Outside of the car industry, is there much need to say "plug-in hybrid electric vehicle" or "extended range electric vehicle", and is the need great enough that acronyms of such jargon will be widely understood? In the future, it is certainly possible, and those in the industry or fanatics are probably already doing so, but as far as the English language goes, not for a while I imagine.

Comment: Don't most people just say "car"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe never. If phonetic pronunciation of acronyms, whether for EVs or anything else, has become or becomes common usage, a largely organic process highly resistant to being forced, only then is it or will it be acceptable.

It's very arbitrary, like it's acceptable to phonetically pronounce the acronym "NASA" like it spells out a word but not the acronym "USDA," which is equally phonetically pronounceable like it spells out a word, the latter being not "acceptable," to use your word, purely for the reason that phonetically pronouncing "USDA" like it spells out a word (i.e., **uhs**-duh) wouldn't be commonly understood as referring to the United States Department of Agriculture.

Then there are acronyms that don't phonetically spell out anything but nonetheless acquire a pronunciation that is also not just saying their letters but that instead creatively derives from the letters or from saying them, like how the Federal National Mortgage Association has the acronym "FNMA," which phonetically spells out nothing, but still, instead of pronouncing each of the letters to refer to it, like is invariably done with the aforementioned example "USDA" in spite of it actually phonetically spelling out a pronounceable word, the acceptable and most often used way to pronounce the acronym "FNMA" is "Fannie Mae," which pronunciation was born out of saying the acronym's letters (i.e., FNMA...eff-enn-em-ay...'ff-enn-em-ay...fennemay...Fannie Mae), first as banking jargon and then more widely as slang, until it became common usage, even to such extent that the Federal National Mortgage Association eventually officially adopted the "Fannie Mae" pronunciation of "FNMA" as a sobriquet and registered it as a trademark.

Like I said, maybe never. That isn't to say those phonetic pronunciations couldn't be or won't be acceptable, but if so, the when of it, regardless of whether by "when" you're referring to time or circumstance, has no hard-and-fast rules, save for those phonetic pronunciations having entered the zeitgeist as common usage, a process that is generally as sudden as it is ineffably etherial.

Comment: The abbreviation eV for electron volt has been pronounced "eevee" for decades. Also note QANTAS, an acronym for "Queensland And Northern Territory Aerial Services", which has been pronounced as a word since at least the 1930s (when QEA - Qantas Empire Airways was established).

Comment: I'm aware. How is that germane to my answer, though?

Comment: I agree with your answer. It is adding a couple of examples which I thought were relevant

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks for the additional examples and thanks for the clarification. 